# How to measure time for Hangfire job execution

Tags: performance, performance-testing, load-testing, hangfire

I would like do some performance tests. For that I will be creating around 20 to 40 jobs in hangfire.
Is there any option to measure the time taken for all the jobs to be successful?

Answer (score 0):

In Hangfire it's possible to [track job progress](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/tracking-progress.html) so you might want to check whether it's implemented already or it's possible to implement.

Otherwise you can wait in loop for an event indicating the job completion: i.e. a row in the database, file apperating in the file system, etc.

With regards to the approach it depends on the load testing tool you're using. If you take i.e. [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) which is one of the most popular and powerful free and open source load testing tools you can

1. Start a job somehow using a suitable [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)
2. Use [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) to periodically poll the job status
3. Add a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract the current status and use it in the While Controller's condition so the loop would exit when the job is finished
4. You can also put everything under the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to measure end-to-end execution time